# Detect if running a debug or release build at runtime

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to determine if the current running react-native app was a debug build? Specifically for android, but hopefully platform agnostic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use DEV flag

```
  if (__DEV__) {
        console.log('I am in debug');
    }
```